# How do you get the default language for a country code in OS?

Tags: ios, localization, iso, nslocale, country-codes

I am trying to format international addresses in iOS (Objective-C).  I have a ISO country code for a particular address but now I need the full country name in the main language for that country.  I realize that there are some countries with multiple languages but those are the exception.  Heck, for a given country code, an array/list of language codes would suffice.  As an example, if I am Japanese and live in Japan but am sending a package to someone in the US, the address needs to be in English and not in Japanese.

So I could do this if I could get the principal language for a particular country code:

"us" -> "en"

"jp" -> "ja"

So basically, I'm looking for code that can produce a table like this:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Country_Codes

Comment: just copy codes from the link and save it in a plist file

Comment: I found something better:  http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt

Answer (score 1):

You already found a table with the data, just use that.

Note that facts are not eligible for copyright* so you do not need permission from anyone nor do you need to comply with open open street map or wikipedia's license.

(*) "Copyright does not cover ideas and information themselves, only the form or manner in which they are expressed." -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#Scope